# existence of a non continuous and unbounded function

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X , d)$ be a non-discrete metric space and $(Y , d)$ be an unbounded metric space. Then is it true that there always exists an unbounded and non-continuous function from $(X , d)$ to $(Y , d)$. If not then can we find any counter example.

Please note that if $(X , d)$ is a discrete metric space then any function from $(X , d)$ to $(Y , d)$ is a continuous function no matter what is structure of the metric space $(Y , d)$. I can able to prove that there always exist a bounded and non-continuous function from $(X , d)$ to $(Y , d)$, provided $(Y ,d)$ has at least two elements. Any help please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The fact that (Y , d) is unbounded guarantees that it has not just two, but infinitely many points.

Comment: Actually for the existence of a bounded and non-continuous function from a non-discrete metric space (X , d) to metric space (Y , d), it is required that (Y , d) must contain at least two elements. However for existence of an unbounded function (Y , d) must be unbounded.

Answer (score 2):

Non-discrete means that there is $x_0\in X$ that is not isolated. And so there is a sequence $(x_n)\subseteq X$ convergent to $x_0$, such that $x_n\neq x_0$. We can also assume that $(x_n)$ is injective, i.e. $x_n\neq x_m$ when $n\neq m$. Because otherwise we can take an injective subsequence of $(x_n)$, which exists by taking element-by-element for smaller and smaller neighbourhoods around $x_0$.

Now let $(y_n)\subseteq Y$ be an unbounded sequence (note that being unbounded guarantees that such sequence exists, finite spaces are always bounded). With that we have all we need. Simply define $f:X\to Y$ by $f(x_n)=y_n$ and define $f(x)$ arbitrarily for any $x\neq x_n$. This function is well defined, unbounded and discontinuous (because unbounded sequences are not convergent). Even more: the discontinuity at $x_0$ is not removable.

Comment: To prove this is discontinuous, note that  $x_n \to x_0$ but $f(x_n) \not\to f(x_0)$.  This requires that we know: a convergent sequence in $Y$ is bounded.

Comment: Very nice construction. Thank you very much.